# Injected checkboxes not being sent to server on post - why?

Tags: html, jquery, browser, insertion

Why are the additional checkboxes I'm injecting into the HTML not being sent to the server when the page is posted?  (Initially, one checkbox is defined when the page is rendered.  I inject more after the page is displayed.)

```
<fieldset id='field_41_23'>
<div class='checkboxes'>
   <div id='input_41_23'>
      <div class='gchoice_41_23_1'>
         <input name='input_23.1' type='checkbox'  value='First Choice'  id='choice_41_23_1'/>
         <label for='choice_41_23_1' id='label_41_23_1'>First Choice</label>
     </div>
     
     --- INJECTED ADDITIONAL CHECKBOX BELOW ---
      <div class='gchoice_41_23_2'>
         ...
      </div>
  
      <div class='gchoice_41_23_3'>
         ...
      </div>
    ...
    </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Here is the code for the injections:

```
jQuery('#input_41_23').append("<div class='gchoice_41_23_2'> ... </div>");
```

Though I select the injected checkboxes and then post, the browser still sends only the first checkbox.

What should be done to have the inserted checkboxes posted as well?  Can/should the browser reparse the HTML so it recognizes the new code?

Comment: Provide more details. How you send request?

Comment: Are you checking the checkboxes? Unchecked checkboxes are not sent.  Can you prove that with the browser "developer tools"?